# BigO Notation: how do I go about calculating it in nested loops? (Beginner)

Tags: computer-science, complexity-theory, big-o

**Edit:** I've been reading on SO for about 3 hours so far and it still isn't making much sense to me (meaning I *have* done my research before asking). Forgot to state that in the OQ.

Alright, I'm completely at a loss with BigO and it makes almost no sense to me when trying to apply other methods of applying it to my code. If anyone can help, I'd like a walkthrough of how to calculate the BigO of the following.

```
int i = 0;
int t = 0;
while(i <= 4){
    // Basic instructions
    int s = 0;
    while(s <= 4){
        // Basic instructions
        t + 2;
        if(conditions){ // Checks if a value isn't in a hashset
            for(int r = 0; r <= t; r++){
                // Basic instructions
                if(conditions){ // This statement can make t equal to any number < t, checks if two strings are identical.
                    // Do stuff
                }else{
                    // Do stuff. 
                }
            }
        }else if(condition){
            i++;
        }
        s++;
    }
}
```

I can put the full code in there if needed, but as far as I can tell I think that should be enough to help me.

My thoughts so far were that (excluding if statements) the notation is something like O(n^3) but because they're nested (and stuff others have told me) it's kinda thrown me off a bit.

**Please note:** this isn't directly for an assignment, but we've been given the task to talk about code we wrote for an assignment and it's complexity. We've been told to show we understand complexity/correctness (in general, not BigO) and how it's applied, but not to apply it to our code since it would be way too complicated to do. I'm only looking at doing this because I want to understand it better for the future. The above code is also a random example, not my actual code meaning I'd still have to change it to fit anyway.

Thanks in advance, we only looked at BigO for about 30 minutes in class and after a load of reading I think I confused myself too much. As I said, if that code isn't appropriate I can change it.

Comment: There are countless questions with good answers about Big-O on SO....

Comment: @MitchWheat I meant to already say that I've been reading on SO for about 3 hours and am none the wiser.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What exactly do I do to get that? The stuff I read on it was a bit confusing.

Comment: @MC In that case it could actually be i in the code I'm working with personally, as that can increase over time too and would likely always be larger than t.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment before you posted to expand it into an answer.

Comment: The conditions can be *very* relevant. Why did you remove them?

Comment: @phant0m I thought it was only calculated by how many times a loop is run. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives Not necessarily. Usually, you count some "expensive operations" and ignore everything else.

Comment: @phant0m ok I'll edit it in now. I was avoiding it as the code could provide an answer to students next year, so I'll pseudo it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not clear what N is, then you could calculate the performance with respect to all variables, and see which one makes more of a difference. In this case, the variables are i, s r and t. The performance strictly speaking is O(i * s * t). r is not included as it's counting up to t, which is where the t in the big O comes from.

The issue though, is that since t cannot exceed 2*s, substituting t for 2s gives O(i * s * 2s). This is the same as O(2 * i * s^2). However, in big O notation all [coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient) are treated as being equal to 1. Therefore, it becomes O(i * s^2). However, i and s cannot exceed 4, and since big O is only concerned about the worst case, it then becomes O(4 * 4^2), as big O is only concerned about the worst possible case. This simplifies to O(64). However, 64 is considered a coefficient*. Therefore, the actual big O is O(1)*.

*Note this isn't strictly correct, as cases like O(x + 64) becomes O(x) and not O(x + 1), in this case, 64 actually becomes a zero not a one.

Meaning, the algorithm as it currently stands is O(1), which is essentially input independent. Which is why there is some confusion coming from the commenters.

The key take away here is that, you may have multiple input size variables, which affect the performance independently, you also might have a [output-sensitive algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm), which has a performance based both on size of the input and the size of the output. Or, you might have an algorithm that is unaffected by the input size.

For a more detailed explanation, see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Oddly enough I did get to O(i*s*t) to start with. So when applying it to something where loop `i` could be run any number of times, and the same with `s` (keeping `t` as it is) would I be looking at O(2n^2)?

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit too quick with my subsuition. Start with the general big O, O(i * s * t), t = 2*s, so then it's O(i * s * (2*s)). However, big O doesn't care about constants, so it becomes O(i * s * s), which is O(i * s^2), where s^2 means s squared. However, s is limited to four, which is O(i * 4^2)= O(16i). Again big O doesn't care about constant factors, so it's simply O(i). Meaning the performance of the algorithm grows linearly with the size of i. Under certain conditions, this could be written as O(N), if i is considered the same as N.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit too quick with my subsuition. Start with the general big O, O(i * s * t), t = 2*s, so then it's O(i * s * (2*s)). However, big O doesn't care about constants, so it becomes O(i * s * s), which is O(i * s^2), where s^2 means s squared. However, s is limited to four, which is O(i * 4^2)= O(16i). Again big O doesn't care about constant factors, so it's simply O(i). Meaning the performance of the algorithm grows linearly with the size of i. Under certain conditions, this could be written as O(N), if i is considered the same as N, which has a special meaning in algorithms.

Comment: I think it's starting to make more sense to me. In my actual code, both i and s could be >= 0 and >= 1 respectively. Does this mean that because I can't ever specify a worst case it would be written as just O(i*s^2)?

Comment: Extending my example a bit to illiterate why it's better to use O(i*s^2). You see, if i will always be less than s, then i is O(s). This means that you then have O(s*s^2) which is O(s^3) (not O(s^2) as said above). However, if i will always be less than sqrt(s), then you have big O(sqrt(s)*s^2) which is O(s^(3/2)). If i cannot exceed a certain value (such as 4, 100 or even 10 billion), then i is O(1), and you get O(s^2). If s is small anything between O(s^2) and O(s^3) has little difference. However, if it's large, the difference in run time can be huge. Which is why big O is important.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me understand it a bit more. Examples I saw previously just jumped from one way of writing it to another without any real explanation of what happened. So with defining it as O(i*s^2) would I need to express that in terms of N or just leave it as it is? How could I get from there to N?

Comment: An example in the differences. If s = 1 million. Then s^2 = 10^12. At a billion operations per second, it's on the order of minutes. However, at s^3, it's on the order of centuries.

Comment: You can probably leave it as it is. N is simply more commonly used in big O. You could transform it into O(N*M) (you have two variables, so just using N is not possible unless you are able do the manipulation I mentioned above), but unless you need to be formal about it, there's really no need, and even less need to actually do it in the algorithm.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification, you've been a huge help!